# reloadData not working in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

#### EDIT #1 - I think this has been solved and working on a fix

I have a UIViewController with calls the following method in viewDidLoad and the reloadData isn't being called. I have tried to put it back on the main thread but it isn't crashing, it just isn't being called and I'm not sure why:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.listTV.frame=CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

  self.listTV.scrollEnabled=YES;
  self.listTV.delegate=self;
  self.listTV.dataSource=self;
  self.listTV.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
  [self.listTV setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

  [self getEachList:self.listID];
}  


-(void)getEachList:(int) listID
{
  NSLog(@"CALLING GET_EACH_LIST");

  void (^someblock)(id JSON)=^(id JSON){
    NSLog(@"at top of completionBlock within getEachMenu");
    NSLog(@"the json: %@", JSON);
    NSDictionary *tmpResult=[JSON objectForKey:@"list"];
    EMBERSList *list=[[EMBERSList alloc] initWithAttributes:tmpResult];
    self.list=list;
    NSLog(@"count of  self.list.listItems: %i", [self.list.listItems count]);
    //[self.listTV reloadData]; <- this didn't work
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.listTV reloadData]; });

  };
  [EMBERSList getCacheAndCallback:listID withHost:EMBERSExtHost() andCallback:someblock];
}
```

Comment: if you uncomment that line, does it work?  :-)  I'd suggest checking to see if "`self.menuTV`" is not nil.

Comment: no, it doesn't work. good point regarding checking nil; I obviously have left out a bunch of code

Comment: Where do you init/alloc the `self.listTV` ?

Comment: yes - I think you are right. This has been a huge refactor and I think this was in Storyboard but for this refactoring needs to be in code.

Comment: Do your `NSLog`s work as expected?

Comment: Do you see the "at top of completionBlock within getEachMenu" line in the debugging console?

Comment: Yes, sorry at lunch now. I think It was that what we had in storyboards is no w all in code.